# How to cleanly exit an external app when the sd-card gets unmounted?

Tags: android, app2sd

my app includes a service, and I'm looking for a way to gracefully exit when the app is installed on the sd-card, and that the sd-card gets unmounted. I don't need the service to restart after the sd-card gets mounted again. I just need to release some files/resources, etc..

I thought about listening for Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_EJECT, but this is apparently broadcast after the external apps have been forced to exit.

Any solution?

Comment: Google does not recommend apps with services allow themselves to be installed on external storage.

Comment: @CommonsWare: I know, but in the docs this is only a "should not", and there also are tips on how to restart the service automatically. Therefore, there should be a way to cleanly exit. By the way, in my case it is not critical if the service shuts down when unmounting. But I'd like to exit cleanly.

Comment: I agree, this seems like a reasonable request.  I'm in the same boat. I'm OK with the service shutting down and not auto-restarting (or I could implement their broadcast suggestion) but I'm disappointed to see the service is just outright killed with no warning.  LogCat simply ends up with an entry that says "Scheduling restart of crashed service..."   

I kind of expected OnDestroy to fire, but it doesn't.  I also thought I might be able to listen for a broadcast, but apparently not.

Comment: What particular aspect of this "unclean" termination do you feel needs cleanup?